# When try to use bin/magento setup:upgrade Getting Error

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Diff\SchemaDiff::diff()must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema, null given, called in /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/DeclarationInstaller.php on line 59 and defined in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Diff/SchemaDiff.php:90
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/DeclarationInstaller.php(59): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Diff\SchemaDiff->diff(NULL, Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema))
#1 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(809): Magento\Setup\Model\DeclarationInstaller->installSchema(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(831): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->declarativeInstallSchema(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(122): Magento\Setup\Model\ in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Diff/SchemaDiff.php on line 90
```

Comment: May be an issue from 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Currently i am not using any 3rd party extensions.

Comment: please share me your Magento version as well as that file too.

Comment: Using Magneto 2.3